# image not storing in folder using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My code is given below i unable to store image in sepecfic folder in codeigniter. Image is storing database table but not store in the specific path.

Controller:

```
if (isset($_FILES['header_image']) && $_FILES['header_image']['name'] != "") {
                    $fileName="header_image_$id";
                    $ext= end(explode('.',$_FILES['header_image']['name']));
                    $file_name=$fileName.".".$ext;
                    $this->_upload('uploads/header_images/', "gif|jpg|png|jpeg", "header_image",$file_name);
                    $this->generic_model->updateRecord("blood_tips",array("header_image"=>'uploads/header_images/'.$fileName.".$ext"), array("id"=>$id));
    }


private function _upload($uploadPath,$allowedTypes,$name,$file_name)
{
    $config['file_name'] = $file_name;
    $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
    $config['allowed_types'] = $allowedTypes;
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';               
    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($name))
    {
        return $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  file upload parameter is different than proposed documentation .

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';  Notice "./" before path.

Comment: I also do it but not ,, :)

Comment: the code here , you uploaded , with proposed changes should work fine .

I can be helpful, if you could upload , complete controller class, and exactly the form code , you are uploading through.

Comment: Doesn't it even displays error due to last if condition? or it also passes that if condition  ?

Answer (score 0):

te correct way to upload file in CI, you need to make like this:

```
    $fileName="header_image_$id";
    $ext= end(explode('.',$_FILES['header_image']['name']));

    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/header_images/';
    $config['file_name']     = $fileName.".".$ext;//The extension provided in the file name must also be an allowed file type.
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = 0;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
```